# Visual selection and replacement in vim

Tags: vim, selection

How can I select different portions of multiple non-contiguous lines and replace them with the same/different text?

Example: Let's say my buffer looks like this-

```
Roses are reed,
Violets aree blue,
Sugaar is sweet,
And so are you,
```

I want to change in 1st line the 3rd word ('reed') to 'red, yellow and green', in 2nd line 'aree' to 'are', in 3rd line 'Sugaar' to 'Sugar and molasses' and in 4th line 'you,' to 'you.'.

Say my cursor is at 'R' of 'Roses'. I want to select all four of these wrongs at once and nothing other the wrongs. After I'm done selecting I want to be able to move to 'reed' by pressing some key (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>), then after changing I want to be able to press some key (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>) and move the next visual selection which is 'aree'.

Is there any plugin that does this?

Comment: Hi Alam, can you provide more details

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl I don't know how to select characters from different lines and different columns. With that I can't do anything.

Comment: just use the `.` operation of vim.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Instead of selecting all and doing the same thing with multiple cursors, just select one do what you want. Jump to the next part and use `.` to repeat the change. [have a look here](https://medium.com/@schtoeffel/you-don-t-need-more-than-one-cursor-in-vim-2c44117d51db) or [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/multiple-cursors-at-desired-location)

Answer (score 1):

There are *multiple cursors* plugins that attempt to create parallel editing functionality seen in other editors to Vim (which is difficult). If I understand your use case right, that wouldn't help here, though, because all places would be edited in the same way (so `reed`, `areee`, etc. would all be replaced with the same `red`).

Instead, what you seem to be asking for, is a way to search for all wrongly spelled words, and then edit them one by one, individually. You can do this with standard search, using regular expression *branches*:

```
/reed\|areee\|Sugaar\|you,/
```

You can then simply press `n`ext to go to the next match after you're done. Note that the branches have to be unique (so I searched for `you,` instead of simply `,`). Adding word boundaries (`\<reed\>` instead of `reed`) is a good idea, too.

#### plugin recommendations

- [multiple cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) is a famous plugin for parallel editing
- My [SearchAlternatives plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4146) lets you add the current word under the cursor as a search branch with a quick (`<Leader>+` by default) key mapping. (However, if you're already on the word, why not correct it immediately?)
- My [SpellCheck plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) populates the quickfix list with all misspelled words and locations. You can then use quickfix navigation (e.g. `:cnext`) to quickly go to each. The plugin also offers mappings to fix spelling errors directly from the quickfix list.

Comment: It works. But I wanted something that worked for not just words, maybe texts that are long enough that I don't want to type and search. I wanted something that could select everything I want to using navigation and something which can on/off selection mode, and then change those texts however I want. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: My SearchAlternatives plugin also provides visual mode mappings, so that you can add the current selection as a search branch. To do that for regular search, too, you can use my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320), or one of its alternatives that provide `{Visual}*`.

Comment: I don't understand properly. In my example (in the question) say I want to select the 1st word of 1st line, everything after the 1st word in the 2nd line and everything except the last word in the 4th line, and then change them one by one. Can I do that with these plugins? I am new to vim, if you could explain, it'd be great.

Comment: How do you "select"? In Vim, that usually means a visual mode selection: You go to the beginning, press `ve` to select one word. With SearchAlternatives, you can then add this to the search pattern via `<Leader>+`. But as you're already there, I wonder why you don't immediately fix the spelling error now, and why you'd want to add this to the search pattern to go back there later. That motivation is missing from your question.

Comment: I am not talking about just spelling errors. I have changed the question a bit. This is what I wanted to mean. Sorry for the confusion. Is this possible?

Comment: It's still not clear to me. _select all four of these wrongs at once_ translates to the search `/reed\|areee\|Sugaar\|you,/` I've given in my answer. That's the generic approach. If that's too much to type for you, for spell checking in particular, there are alternate approaches to navigate to them (`]s` is built-in, or my SpellCheck plugin). But in general, Vim cannot know what you want to "select"; **you** have to tell Vim.

Comment: I'd suggest you try some of the approaches and plugins first. If it helps your workflow, great. If not, you can come back and ask additional, more precise questions later.